# How to avoid this "by no means" redundancy?

Tags: word-request

How to avoid this redundancy here?

> According to the Constitution, the state power was **by no means** to be
>   changed **by means** of a revolution.

Comment: Could you paraphrase the intended meaning? Do you mean "...the state power was not changed due to a revolution"? I am not clear why *means* is used as it makes comprehension difficult. Did you write this or could you cite the source?

Comment: @user3169 - My meaning was that the Constitution of a country forbade the change of the state power by means of a revolution. In other words, the Constitution forbade revolution as a legal way of changing the state power in the country.

Comment: So using that, "According to the Constitution, it was forbidden to change the state power by means of a revolution." would be OK. I am unclear why you used "by no means" in your example.

Comment: @user3169: "I am unclear why you used "by no means" in your example" - Just to emphasize the fact that all kinds of revolutions are forbidden by the Constitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to the Constitution, the state power was by no means to be changed by means of a revolution.

Maybe the following was what you wanted?

> According to the Constitution, the state power was not to be changed by a revolution.

Comment: Thank you. Can I still keep the first "_by no means_"? In other words, can I say like this:  
"According to the Constitution, the state power was _by no means_ to be changed by a revolution"? Or should it be now something like "_in no way_", or "_in no case_", or something else?

Comment: "According to the Constitution, by no means was the state power to be changed by means of a revolution."